# Google Chrome : My statubar disappeared

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Somehow, my Google Chrome status bar disappeared. The usuall status bar only appears on Incognito (private browsing) mode. How to may it reappear? And even if it does, how to make it show the full URL of the link I am about to open?

[edit]
I found that to show the full URL, you can use the [status bar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/status-bar/ojjdiklbbogaliiljdbpbkkkghendjja?hl=en) extension. However, the following questions remain unanswered:

1. Why the status bar was hidden on the first place?
2. How to make it reappear...

Comment: Weird your status bar disappeared. In my case, it was the location bar! :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the official bug thread for this issue:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8663

Apparently, for some users the following solved the issue:

- Open Chrome Settings
- Select "Show Advanced Settings"
- Scroll down to "System"
- Un-check "Use hardware acceleration when available"

Comment: This was the dev-m version. Using your tip resolved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: The issue occurs for me in Chrome version 33 and it is annoying. I don't use any extensions. Link appeared in status bar after applying the setting but after I closed the browser and re-opened, its lost again.

Comment: Or skip 3 first steps and just copy paste this: `chrome://settings/search#hardware` - it may have disappeared, but CMD / CTRL + L still focus on it.

Comment: In my case, just restarting chrome resolved the issue, though. There's no need to disable the [good hardware acceleration](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150212/hardware-acceleration-for-flash-videos-in-google-chrome)!